# sqlite mark duplicates with true or false

Tags: sqlite, count, duplicates, case, window-functions

I need to create a new column in my dataset (duplicate_name) that contains TRUE if there are more than one record for someone or FALSE otherwise. I found this code (I am working with sqlite):
SELECT *,
CASE
WHEN ROW NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY
first_name, last_name) > 1) THEN 'TRUE'
ELSE 'FALSE'
END AS duplicate_name
FROM users;

But when I ran it it gives me something like this (ONLY THE SECOND RECORD IS MARKED AS TRUE):
Carlo  Thomas    male  FALSE
Carlo  Thomas    male  TRUE
Don    Scallion  male  FALSE
Tania  Lopes     female  FALSE

What I need is a table like this (both records with the same name are marked as TRUE):
Carlo  Thomas    male  TRUE
Carlo  Thomas    male  TRUE
Don    Scallion  male  FALSE
Tania  Lopes     female  FALSE

Can someone help me, please.

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `ROW_NUMBER()` use `COUNT(*)` window function:

```
SELECT *, 
       CASE WHEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY first_name, last_name) > 1 THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS duplicate_name 
FROM users;
```

or simpler with a 1 for true and 0 for false:

```
SELECT *, 
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY first_name, last_name) > 1 AS duplicate_name 
FROM users;
```

Comment: I'd also suggest doing this in a view instead of adding a new column to a table; that way it's automatically updated as rows are inserted/deleted without needing a trigger.